# Set IIS AppPool StartMode property using TFS release template

Tags: iis-6, tfsbuild, windows-server-2012

I need to set my AppPool's StartMode to AlwaysRunning.

[image]

I can go ahead and change that setting in IIS -> My-AppPool -> Advanced Settings fine; however I would need to redo it after each release, which is not ideal.

I release my app using TFS release template. I already have an **IIS Web App Manage** task in there and could use the Additional appcmd.exe commands section to do this:

```
set config "Default Web Site/Test" -section:applicationPools -[name='$(TestSite_AppPool)'].startMode:AlwaysRunning
```

All good, however I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR ( message:Can not set attribute "startMode" to value "AlwaysRunning,".. Reason: This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
```

Is this a show-stopper or anything could be done within the TFS template to make it work? Or maybe it is a syntax problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a syntax problem and this works instead:

```
set apppool "TestSite_AppPooll" /autoStart:true /startMode:AlwaysRunning
```